# Como posso bloquear o acesso a páginas da aplicação com filtro de sessão?

Tags: java, session, filtro, servlet-3

Código do Filtro de Sessão

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class FiltroSessaoUsuario implements Filter {

public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if (httpRequest.getAttribute("usuario") != null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("erro-
 login.jsp").forward(httpRequest, httpResponse);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Ocorreu um erro no filtro de sessao do 
usuario.", e);
    }
}

public void destroy() {

}
}
```

Código da lógica de login

```
public class LoginUsuarioLogica implements Logica {
public void executa(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws Exception {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
    usuario.setSenha(request.getParameter("senha"));
    HttpSession sessao = request.getSession();
    if (new UsuarioDAO().validaLogin(usuario)) {
        sessao.setAttribute("usuario", usuario.getEmail());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, 
response);
    } else {
        sessao.invalidate();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("erro-login.jsp").forward(request, 
response);
    }
}
}
```

Código da lógica de logout

```
public class LogoutUsuarioLogica implements Logica {
public void executa(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws Exception {
    if (request.getParameter("parametro").equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
        HttpSession sessao = request.getSession();
        sessao.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere FiltroSessaoUsuario para verificar se a sessão HTTP possui o atributo "usuario", confome exeplo abaixo:

```
public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
    FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            HttpSession sessao = httpRequest.getSession();
            Object usuarioLogado = sessao.getAttribute("usuario");

            if ( usuarioLogado != null) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("erro-login.jsp").forward(httpRequest, httpResponse);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ocorreu um erro no filtro de sessao do usuario.", e);
        }
    }

public void destroy() {

}
```

**É importante informar que a anotação @WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*" }) aplicará o seu filtro para todas as requisições da aplicação**. Inclusive, login.jsp e erro-login.jsp. Sendo que isto não faz sentido porque o filtro não pode validar se o usuário está logado justamente na página que o usuário utiliza para fazer login.

Você não informou como você estruturou seu projeto, então não posso informar com certeza o padrão de URL que você deve informar. Uma opção seria você colocar todas suas páginas JSP restritas em uma pasta diferente das páginas login.jsp e erro-login.jsp, então aplicar o filtro apenas para essa pasta.

Uma proposta de organização de arquivos seria:

```
login.jsp
erro-login.jsp
paginas-restritas
  - pagina1.jsp
  - pagina2.jsp
```

O WebFilter ficaria assim:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/paginas-restritas/*" }) 
public class FiltroSessaoUsuario implements Filter {
...
```

Outra opção menos prática é você definir um URL patterns informando todas as páginas para as quais o filtro deve ser aplicado, deixando de fora login.jsp e erro-login.jsp:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/paginas-restritas/pagina1.jsp","/paginas-restritas/pagina2.jsp"})
```

O inconveniente dessa solução é ter que alterar o urlPatterns para cada nova página que você criar em sua aplicação. Com o tempo, a manutenção desse código  ficará difícil.

Uma terceira opção é você deixar o filtro aplicável para todas as requisições e dentro do código de FiltroSessaoUsuario você programaticamente verifica se a requisição está sendo feita para login.jsp ou erro-login.jsp e invoca chain.doFilter() para que a requisição prossiga:

```
 ...
 String path = httpRequest.getRequestURI().substring(httpRequest.getContextPath().length()).replaceAll("[/]+$", ""); 
 if (path.equalsIgnoreCase("login.jsp") || path.equalsIgnoreCase("erro-login.jsp")) {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
 }
 if ( usuarioLogado != null) {
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
 } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("erro-login.jsp").forward(httpRequest, httpResponse);
 }
 ...
```

Comment: Eu não sei o que está acontecendo agora, pois, o filtro funcionou legal utilizando a proposta de deixar os .JSPs na raiz mesmo, e filtrar pela URL, como vc descreve no último bloco de código. Só estou com apenas um problema: quando acesso a página de login, a página está toda simples sem a aplicação do CSS, e quando eu insiro os dados de login corretos, ele volta a mostrar a tela de login novamente só que com o CSS e JavaScript normal, e só a partir dessa tela é que consigo entrar efetivamente no sistema.

Comment: Isso está acontecendo provavelmente porque seu filtro @WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*" }) está sendo aplicado para todas as requisições feitas ao servidor, inclusive para arquivos CSS e Java Script.

Alterar o filtro para @WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*.jsp" }) deve resolver seu problema

Comment: Bom dia Rodrigo, eu até configurei dessa forma,, inclusive antes de postar aqui no fórum, mas realizar essa alteração (que é num .java), reinicio o Tomcat e ocorre erro de compilação.
Se eu deixar ({ "/*" }) e reiniciar não ocorre nenhum erro no container, mas se eu colocar ({ "/*.jsp" }) o Tomcat não compila e dá erro. Alguma ideia?

Comment: @JosinaldoRocha, se o problema ainda persistir, ponha o log do erro aqui e o conteúdo do seu web.xml

Comment: A única mensagem do erro é: "Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

Comment: No console do Eclipse mostra esse log;

Comment: Olá pessoal. Primeiro gostaria de agradecer pela ajuda de todos. Segundo, gostaria de avisar que resolvi todos os problemas que mencionei aqui no fórum.
No Tomcat estava ocorrendo erro por causa do padrão da URL que configurei ("/*.jsp"), e após correção ficou assim ("*.jsp"), e resolveu.
Com relação a página de login que estava aparecendo sem o CSS, acabei encontrando um erro no código HTML, e havia duas tags "<body>" em cada página (login e erro-login),, e por isso estava sendo interpretado errado pelo browser.
Tudo está rodando legal agora. Vlw!